# How to use CreateDateTime in LINQ to entity expressions

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Because if you try to use DateTime in LINQ expressions you will get:

`Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.`

The best way is to use `DbFunctions.CreateDateTime Method` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn218443(v=vs.113).aspx

**Not working example:**

```
await ctx.Example.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(e => e.Id == id)
    .Select(e => new EducationDTO {
            StartDate =  new DateTime(e.StartDate, 1, 1)
            EndDate = new DateTime(e.EndDate, 1, 1)
    })
    .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**Attempt example:**

```
await ctx.Example.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(e => e.Id == id)
    .Select(e => new EducationDTO {
            StartDate =  DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(e.StartDate, 1, 1, null, null, null) ?? DateTime.Now,
            EndDate = DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(e.EndDate, 1, 1, null, null, null) ?? DateTime.Now,
    })
    .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

In my attempt to use `CreateDateTime` example, CreateDatetime will be null, and I'll just get `DateTime.Now`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is in `e.StartDate`?

Comment: And what is your expectation in `e.StartDate`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the non working example is correct (i.e. `e.StartDate` / `e.EndDate` are `int` and represent year) and the only problem is the unsupported `DateTime` constructor.

As you mentioned, the correct method is `DbFunctions.CreateDateTime` which has the following signature:

```
public static Nullable<DateTime> CreateDateTime(
    Nullable<int> year,
    Nullable<int> month,
    Nullable<int> day,
    Nullable<int> hour,
    Nullable<int> minute,
    Nullable<double> second
)
```

What is not mentioned in the documentation (although this is the typical database expressions behavior) is that the result is `null` when **any** of the parameters is `null`. Which also means that if **all** the parameters are **not** `null`... - indeed, the result is not `null` as well.

So, the correct usage in your scenario would be like this:

```
.Select(e => new EducationDTO {
        StartDate = DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(e.StartDate, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).Value,
        EndDate = DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(e.EndDate, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).Value,
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Would something along these lines work for you?

Disclaimer - I'am still not 100% sure of your input/output situation. Do you have  `DateTime` or `DateTime?`, what you expect to convert from and to, etc

Create extension

```
public static class Ext
{

    public static DateTime? SpecialDate(this DateTime? v)
    {
        if (!v.HasValue) return null;
        return new DateTime(v.Value.Year, 1, 1);
    }

    public static DateTime? SpecialDate2(this DateTime? v)
    {
        if (!v.HasValue) return null;
        // neither this
        return new DateTime().AddYears(v.Value.Year - 1);
        // or this - uses parameterized constructor
        //return DateTime.MinValue.AddYears(v.Value.Year - 1);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
    DateTime? dt2 =  null;
    DateTime? dt1 =  DateTime.Now;

    Console.WriteLine(dt2.SpecialDate());
    Console.WriteLine(dt1.SpecialDate());
    Console.WriteLine(dt1.SpecialDate2());
```

Result

> ```
> <-- this is empty string <br>
> ```
>
> 1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM
>   1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM

And in your case it will be

```
StartDate = e.StartDate.SpecialDate()
```